# Is it possible to debug a .NET Framework application that is deployed to IIS on my local machine?

Tags: debugging, iis, .net-4.8

I have incorporated Azure authentication in to a .NET application on my local development machine. When I debug/run the application in Visual Studio the app runs just fine.

I have deployed the application to IIS on my local development machine and have configured a new site binding of type HTTPS which uses an SSL certificate that I have created locally and added to my "Trusted Root Certification Authorities" store. When I try to browse the application through IIS, I get a generic error message that is generated by the Application_Error method in my global.asax.cs file.

Is it possible for me to use a debugger to "step through" code that has been actually deployed in IIS? I think that I have found MSDN documentation that describes doing this for a .NET Core application (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/development-time-iis-support?view=aspnetcore-2.1) but I my app is written in .NET 4.8 so I don't think it applies for me.

Comment: Add `Thread.Sleep` to certain parts of your web app, so that you have extra time to attach VS to the worker process before critical code execution.

Comment: Lex Li - I've downloaded the "VS 2019 Remote Debugger". Do I have to be running the application already in order to be able to "attach" the debugger to it?

Comment: Remote debugger only gives you extra abilities to attach to processes on a remote machine, but you still need to trigger those processes before attaching.

Comment: Do you know of documentation that describes how this works? I'm not really sure how to get started with remote debugging...

Comment: Hi, has the problem been solved? If you think my reply is helpful to you, you can mark it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To debug an ASP.NET application that has been deployed to IIS, install and run the remote tools on the computer where you deployed your app, and then attach to your running app from Visual Studio.

For more information about "Remote Debug ASP.NET on a Remote IIS Computer", you can refer to this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/remote-debugging-aspnet-on-a-remote-iis-7-5-computer?view=vs-2019#:%7E:text=After%20the%20app%20deploys%20successfully,under%20the%20File%20Publish%20options.).